# Importing XML with XML-Deserializer and Serializing with DataContract-Serializer

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, deserialization, datacontractserializer

Hy guys,

I have a big distributed project in which I normally use the DataContractSerializer (Requirement, must not be changed).

Now I have to import some XML-Files (from Siemens TIA Openness) which I want to achieve with the help of the XML-Deserializer. So far it works great.

Now I have the object of the imported XML at the backend and need to transfer it to the frontend with the DataContractSerializer.

When I do that, I get the CommunicationException (SocketConnection aborted).
I think thats because, I added the [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribut] and so on to my class and its members.

I read that one can add both the XMLSerializer-Attribute AND the DataContractSerializer-Attribute to the class. That doesn't change anything.

Now I could use a way to "override" the XMLSerializer and use the DataContractSerializer instead.

If somebody could help me, any suggestions would be highly appriciated.

Comment: I would use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to verify your suspicions.  A socket would only close if a timeout occurred or bad data was sent over the connection.  I'm suspecting that the connection requires xml data and the data is not xml, or the connection is closing before all the end tags are received.

Answer (score 1):

Your question targeting to Serialize and Deserialize an Class.
You should implement IXmlSerializable
then overwrite
        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        public void WriteXml(XmlReader reader)